# Split values in a column and reassign it to a new column

Tags: r

In my DataFrame, one the columns has a value that is a combination of [state,country]

[image]

I tried this code:

```
voivodeshipdf <- voivodeshipdf %>% mutate(state =  as.character(unlist(str_split(voivodeship, ','))[1]))
```

but it only reassigns the value of the first row.

[image]

Please how do I update my code to split the right values for each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be `separate`

```
library(tidyverse)
voivodeshipdf %>%
   separate(voivodeship, into = c('state', 'newcol'), sep=",", remove = FALSE) %>%
   select(-newcol)
```

Or `extract`

```
voivodeshipdf %>%
     extract(volvodeship, into = 'state', '^([^,]+),.*', remove = FALSE)
```

or with `word`

```
voivodeshipdf %>%
     mutate(state = word(volvodeship, 1, sep=","))
```

---

The issue in the OP's code is that is subsetting the `list` with `[1]`, which would select the first `list` element as a `list` with one vector and it is getting assigned to the column due to recycling

Instead, what we need is to extract the first element from the `list` output of `str_split` with `map` or `lapply` (`map` would be more appropriate in `tidyverse` context)

```
voivodeshipdf %>% 
        mutate(state =  map_chr(str_split(voivodeship, ','), first))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `sub` here for a base R option:

```
voivodeshipdf$state <- sub("^.*, ", "", voivodeshipdf$voivodeship)
voivodeshipdf$voivodeship <- sub(",.*$", "", voivodeshipdf$voivodeship)
```

Sample script:

```
voivodeship <- "Greater Poland voivodeship, poland"
sub("^.*, ", "", voivodeship)
sub(",.*$", "", voivodeship)

[1] "poland"
[1] "Greater Poland voivodeship"
```